# mysql Undefined index on dynamic query

Tags: mysql

I have a database table that stores values to be used in a dynamic query, which pulls data from a table name stored in another column.  For examples, one entry might be:

```
selects                                             | tableName
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
fName,lName,email,phone,address,city,state,zip      | foobar
```

I then take this value and use it to generate a dynamic query then i then run with my db class... something like this:

```
$fields = $connection->runQuery("SELECT selectItems, tableName FROM foo;");
$query = "SELECT " . $fields[0]['selectItems'] . " FROM " . $fields[0]['tableName'] . ";";
$results = $connection->runQuery($query);
```

That works fine, but if i try to change the selects values to something like this:

```
selects                                                                        | tableName
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CONCAT(fName, ' ', lName) as fullName,email,phone,address,city,state,zip      | foobar
```

I get an error saying:

> Undefined index: CONCAT(fName, ' ', lName) as fullName

How can i make it run the $query variable as if I had typed it in myself?

---

Here's a C/P of one of the "selects" values straight from the DB:

```
visitTimestamp as visitTS,firstName,lastName,CONCAT(apptDate,apptTime) as apptTS,address,phone,email,currentCarYear,currentCarMake,currentCarModel,currentCarValue,personID
```

When I do echo $query, I'm shown the following:

```
SELECT visitTimestamp as visitTS, firstName, lastName, CONCAT(apptDate, apptTime) as apptTS, address, phone, email, currentCarYear, currentCarMake, currentCarModel, currentCarValue, personID FROM foo
```

---

I copied and pasted the echoed $query string and ran it through phpMyAdmin and it worked just fine.  Any ideas why it wouldn't be running when it's executed as a variable?

Comment: You have an extra comma at the end of your CONCAT.

Comment: Yeah, sorry... just a typo in here... it's not like that in the DB

Comment: can you echo `$fields[0]['selectItems']` and see what you get ?

Comment: I edited the main to show the echo $query results in

Comment: and you get the error after you execute the query `Undefined index: CONCAT(fName, ' ', lName) as fullName` ?

Comment: Correct... no errors until the query is executed.

Comment: well as far as the query is concern there is nothing wrong, just wondering if the result set is trying to set the data as `CONCAT(fName, ' ', lName) as fullName` instead of `fullName` in other words the resultset should access the data something as `$results[0][fullName]`

Comment: I tried just doing a "fName as firstName" instead of the CONCAT and it threw the same error.

Comment: @Brds sure that the field called `fName`?

Comment: 100% sure... just doubled checked also

Comment: @Brds You could find the error?